# ¿porque no estoy pudiendo instalar multer desde npm?

Tags: nodejs, npm

hago correr el comando `npm install --save multer` y me sale este error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 178469 while parsing
>   near '...} npm ERR!       } npm ERR!     } npm ERR!   } npm ERR! } npm
>   ERR! '
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-21T16_46_22_370Z-debug.log

¿que es lo que debo hacer para solucionar esto?

Comment: Si añades el contenido de ese log quizá podamos averiguar algo más.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La instalación funciona

[image: instalacion]

Es probable que la cache esté corrupta por una descarga anterior. Debes ejecutar alguno de los comandos de la [cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html#description)

```
npm cache clean
```

para limpiarla o también puedes usar

```
npm cache verify
```

que buscará problemas en la caché y los resolverá.

Si esa no es la causa entonces es muy posible que tu entorno de red esté bloqueando las descargas de `npm` así que debes verificarlo con tu administrador de red.

Hay otra posibilidad de que si editas manualmente el `package.json` o el `package-lock.json` y produces JSON inválido al intentar actualizar alguna dependencia se produzca un error similar. La solución para este caso es revisar minuciosamente el `package.json`, borrar el lock e instalar nuevamente todas las dependencias con `npm install`.

Comment: solo me pasa este error en este proyecto y si corro npm cache clean me sale otro error.